# How to make jquery ui-autocomplete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need to add jquery ui-autocomplete function for my form input, in which it should suggest the numbers already added, my form-input code was

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Purchase No </span>
      {!! Form::input('text', 'purchase_number', $purchase_number, array('id' => 'purchase_number', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'purchase_number')) !!}
    </div>
```

And what i tried with jquery script was,

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $("#purchase_number").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 0,
  select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#purchase_number').val(ui.item.purchase_number);
  }
})
.focus(function () {
  $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});

$("#purchase_number").autocomplete().data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  return $("<li>")
  .append("<a>" + item.purchase_number + "</a>")
  .appendTo(ul);
};

});

</script>
```

I am very new in doing auto-complete function and i might have done some minor mistakes and i request you to give a clear explanation about what changes i need to make in it..

Comment: Can you give a fiddle?

Comment: This is my fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/uyxje4a5/ .. The ui auto-complete class was not applied to the form..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery autocomplete example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558556/jquery-autocomplete-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the simple code first using jquery. Include `jquery.js`, `jquery.ui.js` and `jquery.ui.css` in your page first.

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];


  $("#purchase_number").autocomplete({
     source:availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-group-addon">Purchase No </label>
              <input type ="text" id="purchase_number" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with some simpler code and then keep on extending the logic! Check below snippet for minimal version of code.

```js
$("input#search-textbox").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="search-textbox" class="topic-picker ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" maxlength="100" name="q" acceskey="b" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter text" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```